# Is there a library like ImGui with the ability to customize frames, buttons, sliders, etc. in the windows for OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm trying to write a game on OpenGL using C++. From third-party libraries for creating windows (widgets?) Inside OpenGL, I was able to add ImGui to my project, create a window and attach some functions to it. But I did not find information like changing the style of this window. Specifically, in this situation, I need to create the starting window of the game (start the game, settings, exit, etc.) and create in-game windows (inventory, character menu, minimap, chat, etc.). I heard about Qt, but given the size they require, my program will weigh 3-4 times more than we would like. In addition, I do not need any super high-quality graphics and a large set of visualization capabilities. I would like to understand what my program consists of and have a set of basic concepts about how this is implemented. Could you advise: is there a similar library with the ability to create and edit the style of in-game windows (maybe in ImGui this function is still there?) with open source code in C++?

Comment: Unfortunately, this type of question ("what technology to use") is considered off-topic here. Maybe this would be more welcomed on [GDNet](https://www.gamedev.net/), where their format is more appropriate for this kind of discussion.